# Type of Object Template

Tags: c#, .net, ascx

```
Inherits="CMS.Core.ObjectTemplate<App.Core.Member>
```

I am a little stuck as it is telling me that the inheriting is coming from an Object Template, but what I am not sure is the 'Type' of that object template. This is a question given to me in a quiz and wanted to ask what is the type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to an object of type CMS.Core.ObjectTemplate then it's type should be CMS.Core.ObjectTemplate'1. This is a Generic Type.